# Episerver form -File Upload custom validation

Tags: episerver

I am using episerver form with file upload element and a submit button.Apart from the file upload element being required, additional validation for duplicate file name is also required.

Can I use form submitting event on form initialization module &add custom validator to restrict user adding duplicate file name rather than modifying the existing file upload element

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/content-cloud/v1.2.0-forms/docs/creating-form-element-with-validator

Comment: Thank you for the response Ted .I did went through this link but this one is a client side validation &the custom validator I am building is based on values to be checked from the submission data ie Filename column.For this,I have created a formsinitiailization event which is where I am trying to not just validate but add a new column Filename that comes from File upload column by extracting the file name from file upload data .Any feedback on the approach is appreciated